# ENS is not finalizing my auction and I need to reopen it again and again

Tags: ens

I opened an auction and bidded. After that i revealed my bid. Unfortunately there is no option for finalizing the autcion, like in others. Instead after the RevealPeriod ends. ENS says I need to reopen and than shows me my bid from before. I have the issues with three auctions. Another strange thing is, that etherscan doesn't shows my bid [image: see picture], but ENS Registrar shows it... Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that list is all the events associated with the name that you bid on, then the problem is that you did not reveal your bid.

The process is:

- Start auction
- Submit bid
- Reveal bid
- Finalise bid

You can not finalise an auction that you did not win, and you can not win if you do not reveal your bid.

Comment: Yes I know, but its not possible for me to bid, because ENS recognizes my previous bid and therefore i can not reveal again. The only thing I never able to do was finalizing...

Comment: There is no reason to make a new bid as you have already done so. You can only reveal in the reveal period. Wait until the reveal period, reveal your bid, then finalise the auction after it ends.

Comment: I don't make new bids. The only thing I do is OpenAuction (which triggers the startAuction function). After that as I said, the system recognizes my previous bid, so I'm not able to bid again. When the Reveal Period starts, the system recognizes, that i have revealed before, so the option does not exist anymore. the only thing it never showed me was the Finalize option...

Comment: It sounds like you are using a specific user interface. Because what you have done is not typical, the interface probably does not handle what you have done. The best way would be to reveal the bid through the command line at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

**Original Bid**

Your original bid has now been burned (to [this "dead" address](https://etherscan.io/address/0x000000000000000000000000000000000000dead)). After 19 days, anyone can [cancel and remove your bid](https://github.com/ethereum/ens/blob/master/contracts/HashRegistrarSimplified.sol#L434), if you haven't unsealed it. There are bots that do this automatically, so it's virtually guaranteed that one did already.

**Bids not Visible on Etherscan**

The first bid is in the `startAuctionsAndBid` transaction at the bottom of your screenshot. Any bids made in isolated transactions (with `newBid`), will not be visible in Etherscan. The .eth Registrar Auction is designed to have blind bidding, so it's not possible for other people (or other systems like Etherscan) to tell that you have placed a bid on a name.

**Getting Your Name**

It appears that whatever tool you are using to get the name might be getting in the way more than helping. I would suggest trying [MyEtherWallet.com](https://myetherwallet.com/). You should start from scratch and do the complete cycle: start, bid, reveal, finalize cycle.

The good news is that it looks like you have a unique-enough name that you will be able to win it for the minimum bid of 0.01 eth. Otherwise, someone else would have bid on and won the name by now.